# How to output JavaScript into a Textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry I'm rather new to coding in JavaScript. I'm trying to make a simple program that takes two inputs, for base and height, and outputs the area of a triangle.

My HTML is this:

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
        <label for="">Width (b): </label><input type="textbox" name="width"></input><br>
        <label for="">Height (h): </label><input type="textbox" name="height"></input><br>
        <button onClick="calculateArea()">Calculate area</button>
</form>

<label for="output">The area is: </label><input type="textbox" name="output"></input>
```

And my JavaScript is this:

```
function calculateArea() {

var base = document.getElementById('width').value;
var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
var out = (1/2) * parseFloat(base) * parseFloat(height);

document.output.value = out;

}
```

I've tried changing the name="output" of the output textbox to an ID and using getValueByID, but it has made no difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get rid of form tag,than change javascript code a little
Here is the working example:
[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BHeAp/)

HTML:

```
<label for="">Width (b): </label><input type="textbox" name="width"></input><br>
<label for="">Height (h): </label><input type="textbox" name="height"></input><br>
<button onClick="calculateArea()">Calculate area</button><br>
<label for="output">The area is: </label><input type="textbox" name="output"></input>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function calculateArea() {
var base = document.getElementsByName('width')[0].value;
var height = document.getElementsByName('height')[0].value;
var out = (1/2) * parseFloat(base) * parseFloat(height);

document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value= out;

}
```

Comment: That worked brilliantly and I can see what you were going for with it too. I'm not sure how the form tag was messing it up, but it's pristine now, so thank you!

Comment: The form doesn't matter. The important part is document.getElementById for the output box.

Answer (score 1):

To get to an input element you need to use `document.<formName>.<inputName>`, therefore:

Put the output inside the form

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
    <label for="">Width (b): </label><input type="textbox" name="width" /><br />
    <label for="">Height (h): </label><input type="textbox" name="height" /><br />
    <button onClick="calculateArea(); return false;">Calculate area</button><br />

    <label for="">The area is: </label><input type="textbox" name="output" />
</form>

function calculateArea() {
    var base = document.input.width.value;
    var height = document.input.height.value;
    var out = (1/2) * parseFloat(base) * parseFloat(height);

    document.input.output.value = out;
}
```

## JSBin

**Note:** This is all assuming you don't want to use ID's.

Comment: I can use IDs if I want, but this doesn't appear to work, it eats the inputs but displays no output.

Comment: I have, I copied it directly into my code but when I put in inputs and hit calculate, the only change is that the inputs disappear, no output is displayed, not even briefly.

Comment: Added a link to JSBin. Also, the form is submitted when you press the button, so I've added `return false;` in the `onClick` event to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<label for="">Width (b): </label>
<input type="textbox" name="width" id="width" value="2"/><br />
<label for="">Height (h): </label>
<input type="textbox" name="height" id="height" value="3"/><br />
<input type="button" id="calcButton" value="Calculate area" />
<br/>
<label for="output">The area is: </label>
<input type="textbox" name="output" id="output"/>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('calcButton').onclick = calculateArea;

function calculateArea() {
    var base = document.getElementById('width').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var out = (1/2) * parseFloat(base) * parseFloat(height);
    document.getElementById('output').value = out;
}
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/T7mzd/) ...